# Check constraint over two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I want to add a `Check Constraint` to a table for server 2005 but cannot work it out.

```
MemberId ClubId MeetingId
1        100    10
2        100    10
3        100    10
7        101    10  <-This would throw a check constraint
1        100    11 
2        100    11
```

I do not want to have more than one `ClubId` for a single `MeetingId`
Basically a `ClubId` can only belong to a single `MeetingId` but can have more than one member assigned.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is this table denormalized for performance reasons? Is `MeetingID` an FK? If so, is there a `ClubId` column in the meeting table?

Comment: If that's so, isn't ClubId an attribute of a particular meeting, rather than an attribute of this (Attendees?) table?

Comment: Reason for club Id is because this is a old legacy system where the creator decided to create a PK based on those three fields! Ugly but it is the way it is

Comment: How much of a hassle would it be to correct the schemata?

Comment: A slow but sure process! I am on my way but just need to add some constraints to make sure data is cleansed before I do so!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a function in a Check Constraint is one option but you could create an [INDEXED VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) that accomplishes the same restriction.

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_UNIQUE_MEETINGID WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
  SELECT  ClubID
          , MeetingID
          , COUNT_BIG(*)
  FROM    YourTable
  GROUP BY
          ClubID
          , MeetingID
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UIX_VIEW_UNIQUE_MEETINGID ON VIEW_UNIQUE_CLUBID (MeetingID)
```

Comment: Got error `Cannot schema bind view 'VIEW_UNIQUE_MEETINGID' because name 'MemberMeetings' is invalid for schema binding.`

Comment: @Rippo - you need to use a two-part name to refer to your table, e.g. `dbo.MemberMeetings` if it's in the `dbo` schema.

Comment: Duh! thanks @Lieven, this works really nicely. Now to work out why it works :)

Comment: @Rippo, the indexed view is essentially a table that's a subset of your original table. The subset only contains the ClubID & MeetingID (COUNT_BIG is only necessary to be able to use a GROUP BY). On this subset table, there's a unique constraint on MeetingID.

Answer (score 2):

inferred from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

EDIT: tried the code and fixed it after @rippos comment

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckFnctn()
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @retval int
   SELECT @retval = (select max(cnt) from (select COUNT(distinct ClubID) cnt FROM CheckTbl group by MeetingId) as t )
   RETURN @retval
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE CheckTbl ADD CONSTRAINT chkRowCount CHECK (dbo.CheckFnctn() <= 1 );
GO
```

Comment: +1 but if memory serves me well, this will fail if you `UPDATE` ClubId or MeetingID. To resolve this, you should pass both ClubID and MeetingID to the function.

Comment: This can also fail under snapshot isolation I think. Look for articles by Hugo Kornelis or Alex Kuznetsov on this.

Comment: @Lieven and @Martin Thanks for the comments. I only did ad hoc Google search. I never used check constraints in praxis.

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work as intended. Did you try it out yourself first?

Comment: @Rippo. Oops tried it and fixed it. I guess @Lieven and @martins comments still apply.

Comment: +1 anyway, :P thanks, have decided to go with @Lieven as it works really nicely